# kie workbench unable to find kie execution server

Tags: drools, kie-workbench, kie-server

I have `kie` workbench and `kie` execution server.

Execution server is runnig on

```
http://localhost:7080/kie-server/
```

and I can check its availability via request to `services/rest/server/`.

Also I have a workbench, running on

```
http://localhost:8080/kie-wb
```

and I can work with it via UI (direct REST calls cause `unauthorized` response).

I want to register new server with a container and set as endpoint my execution server on `7080` port.

However in workbench via scanner it's unable to find any endpoint - so it seems my execution server is unable to connect to workbench

I start it with these parameters

```
D:\installed\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-Copy\bin>set JAVA_OPTS=   -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.dialect=oorg.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.ds=jdbc/jbpmB  
-Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller -Dorg.kie.server.id=first-kie-server
```

Where I set workbench controller as `localhost:8080/kie-wb`.

What's the problem?
I am using `6.3` versions for both workbench and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

The culprit was me. Accidentally I used `snapshot` of `execution server` artifact. And it wasn't trying to connect to controller.

When I used the proper artifact it started to work fine.